# Add a Record to Quickbook Intuit

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I need to create an application to add record (Income and Spending) to Intuit Quickbook Self Employed.please kindly advice me about source code to add a record. i have no idea anything. but i have got it's references. now I need only source code.please help me.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: C#..please help me to do this..

Comment: Is this QuickBooks Online, or QuickBooks for Windows, or QuickBooks for Mac?

Comment: https://developer.intuit.com/sampleapps here is the developer site of expecting quick book. i need to use online.because i need to connect this quick book to my application develop by c#

Comment: That website is for both QuickBooks Online, and QuickBooks for Windows. You can connect to both QuickBooks Online, and QuickBooks for Windows using C#. So, which version of QuickBooks are you using?